# R data.table return NA when using .I to get row number

Tags: r, data.table

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(A=c(NA,3,5,0,1,2),B=c("foo","foo","foo","bar","bar","bar"))

dt
#>     A   B
#> 1: NA foo
#> 2:  3 foo
#> 3:  5 foo
#> 4:  0 bar
#> 5:  1 bar
#> 6:  2 bar
#simple filter
dt[,.I[A>1]]
#> [1] NA  2  3  6

dt[A>1,which=TRUE]
#> [1] 2 3 6
```

I was expecting those two should return the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former case uses `base` R logic for subsetting; the latter case uses `data.table`'s slightly different logic for subsetting.

`data.table` excludes `NA` from filtering:

```
dt[A > 1]
#    A   B
# 1: 3 foo
# 2: 5 foo
# 3: 2 bar
# compare to base logic:
setDF(dt)
dt[dt$A > 1, ]
#     A    B
# NA NA <NA>
# 2   3  foo
# 3   5  foo
# 6   2  bar
setDT(dt)
```

You can see this in action a bit more by adding some diagnostics to your first statement:

```
dt[, {
    idx = A > 1
    print(idx)
    print(seq_len(.N)[idx])
    .I[A>1]
}]
# [1]    NA  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [1] NA  2  3  6
# [1] NA  2  3  6
```

The `base` logic is that `NA` means "unknown", so whether to keep or drop the element at `NA` indices is also unknown, therefore the output has to be `NA`. From `?"["`:

> #### NAs in indexing
>
> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character `NA` index picks an unknown element and so returns `NA` in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and `NULL` for a list. (It returns `00` for a raw result.)

vs. from `?data.table`:

> #### `i`
>
> integer and logical vectors work the same way they do in `[.data.frame` except logical `NA`s are treated as `FALSE`.